# Finding the Maximum of a Directed Graph

Tags: c++, nodes, multimap, directed-graph, edges

I am given a [Directed Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) that is not weighted. If traveling only with the direction of the edges, if I am given a vertex I want to know if every other vertex is reachable. If the graph is a [Complete Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) this is obvious. I'm interested in the case where the graph is incomplete.

As far as implementation I store each connection in a `multimap`. The `multimap` key edge tail the `multimap` value is the edge head. So say that I have the following pairs:

- (1, 2)
- (2, 3)
- (1, 4)

In this graph if 1 was the given node, each node can be directly or indirectly reached. If another pair was added to the `multimap`: (5, 3) 5 would not be directly or indirectly reachable from 1, nor would any node but 3 be reachable from 5, so no given node in this graph would be able to reach all other nodes.

My question is this: If all I'm doing with this graph is testing if a single node can reach all other nodes, should I add edges to the `multimap` to make all indirect connections direct and then check if all nodes are connected to the given node? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So you're using the multimap as an adjacency list? Are you asking us if you should insert adjacencies in this list if two nodes can reach each other? I would strongly recommend against such an approach. If later you want to perform any graph traversal, your structure will be polluted with edges that aren't really there.

If you really need to memoize such information, use a separate structure for reachability.

Comment: But in answer to the question, there isn't some kind of traversal function available to me. I need to find all the indirectly connected nodes and see if everything is there?

Comment: @JonathanMee: If the absolutely *only* thing you are doing with your adjacency list is using it to solve your reachability problem, then it's fine to mix. In fact, I wouldn't call it an adjacency list at that point, but a reachability list that is initialized to the adjacency list.

Comment: @JonathanMee: You will need to perform a DFS at each vertex in your graph, and store the reached nodes. Perhaps you are trying to memoize the results of previous DFS searches with your multimap to speed things along? I think the worst case time complexity will be the same as just performing a DFS on each vertex separately and not caching the result. (But in complete graphs or near complete graphs, the memoization could save a lot of processing time, as many new vertices you check will already have an adjacency list of size V)

Comment: I am *only* using this `multimap` for reachability and then throwing it away. So if I understand your comment correctly it would make sense to treat the `multimap` as a "reachability map" and update each node with all possible nodes it can reach. Having said that, does it make sense to just start doing the DFS at the node in question and go from there?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Short answer: yes. Long answer: Things are going to get weird when you want to perform a DFS at any node because its reachability list will be changing during the DFS. So to combat that, perform the DFS and then insert newly reached nodes into the multimap. Again, there's probably a better structure for this. I mentioned `std::map<vertex, std::vector<vertex>>`, but I think that `std::map<vertex, std::set<vertex>>` would actually be more appropriate because the `set` will handle duplicates when you try to insert visited nodes from the DFS.

Comment: Or, separate the adjacency list and the reachability list. I'm all for that. It makes things easier to understand, and your code easier to write. The time and space complexity will be identical.